# Resizing SceneNodes

Tags: c++, scale, ogre

I'm using a Prefab Cube in my ogre project and I want to set its to exactly 10x10x10. The only way I see is to use `setScale`, but I don't know the initial dimensions of the scene node. I've found some old topics on ogre forums, but they rely on bounding boxes, which apparently changed through time.

Answer (score 2):

If you go down on OGRE source code, you can see that default size is 100.

For reference see *createPlane()*, *createCube()* and *createSphere()* in *OgrePrefabFactory.cpp*.